# Problem with Ruby Documentation

Tags: ruby, documentation, overloading, method-signature

I am new with Ruby and I don't understand ruby Documentation.I cut a piece of ruby documentation. please explain completely this piece.
thanks

[image]

Comment: params in square brackets are optional

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as "not a real question", as you haven't explained which part you don't understand. However, for future reference, please don't paste text in an image - it makes it unreadable for visually impaired readers, and impossible to machine translate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are [signatures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_signature) of `File#open` method. As Ruby doesn't support [method overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overloading), there is just one such method, but accepting different combinations of arguments (and potentially returning different things).

And to clarify the syntax, the first form in your screenshot:

```
open(filename, mode='r'[, opt]) -> file
```

means that the first form of `File#open` method expects following arguments:

- filename (mandatory)
- mode (optional, with default value `'r'`)
- opt (probably a hash supporting different additional options)

and that it returns a file object.

Comment: Excuse me , what is the return of first,second,third,fourth form of open ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you would give the URL from which you pasted the screenshot. Anyway, forms without block (first two) return the file handle object (of `File` class), and block forms (latter two) return anything the block iself returns.

Comment: Mladen Jablanović , I am so thankful from you.I take this screen shot from ruby documentation that installed with ruby 1.9.2 p180, do you know a better documentation ?